# Java: Using gridbaglayout with parent class and subclass

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm doing simple calculator. I'm done with GUI, but before I start doing handling events, I would like to optimize my code. I did all of my code within one class, and I did 13 times almost the same thing, setting gridBagConstraints for each item I have. To make it better I made a class Button in different file, with constructor that will set all parameters in gridBagConstraint. In eclipse I get a red cross next to variable gbce(gridBagConstraints)'gbce cannot be resolved to a variable'. I paste code only for one button. Other buttons will have different parameters, but once I'll know how to do one I'll know how to do others. Could you give me some advice?

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame {
.
.
.
private JPanel pane;

public Calculator() {

    super("Calculator");
    pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    okej = new Button(0.5,0.2,2,1,0,1);
    pane.add(okej, gbce);
.
.
.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
}
public class Button {


public Button(Double weightx, Double weighty, int gridwidth, int gridheight, int gridx, int gridy ){
    GridBagConstraints gbce = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbce.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    gbce.weightx = weightx;
    gbce.weighty = weighty;
    gbce.gridwidth = gridwidth;
    gbce.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbce.gridheight = gridheight;
    gbce.gridx = gridx;
    gbce.gridy = gridy;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: If you are using the same constraints for each button, you can just make one instance of it and use that for each button.

Comment: I find out an answer. I just did a method within class that set gridBagConstraints for button.